# How to define and deploy a custom processor in CherryPy

Tags: cherrypy

I am making a certain client -> server application using CherryPy as the web server.
I will be needing to create a request with a large content-length header while sending about 80% of the size of the content but then i don't want CherryPy to read the post data based on the content-length i sent, i want to read it manually and write to another file. but it seems CherryPy times out waiting for whole content-length.

In other words i want to read the incoming post stream manually but still allow CherryPy to process the request headers (and not the body)

UPDATE: I think I can do this with a 'Custom Processor' : http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cpreqbody.html , but i still don't understand how i can write a processor and call it in my application.

Comment: This just seems wrong. Can you provide more info about what you're trying to do?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is send data to the webserver via HTTP POST, but the since the data i want to send is dynamically generated there is no way i would know the content-length tha i should send to the web server (and no i don't want to use Transfer-Encoding: chunked).

Comment: Then why not send it in separate requests as more data gets available?

Comment: I did that but i do not want the overhead that that could possibly yield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing it with [rfile](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.rfile), but see the warning. You should really look for a solution that doesn't break the standards. Perhaps use WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks. `rfile` it is.